# unable to use symfony console or php bin/console

Tags: symfony, console

I'm using Symfony 5 and I'm trying to improve a 1-year-old project (that was working well and hosted).

To add a new page I had to install the make bundle.

So I typed composer require --dev symfony/maker-bundle after upgrade Symfony and composer.

This operation worked well. But then, I wanted to see the list of available commands with this bundle and typed "Symfony console list make", and got this error :

[image]

Looking for a solution, I edited composer.json (which look like a bad idea) following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57393132/error-code-1-cacheclear-during-composer-require)

Now I'm in trouble with this error:

[image]

I'm stuck on it, cannot find a solution on the internet or understand what the error is saying. Does anyone have an idea or a helpful link?

I also tried to clear:pool: cache but it's impossible since I can't use the Symfony console.

Comment: bin/console not symfony console

Comment: as you can see, i tried both. I normal case, php bin/console do the same that symfony console.

Comment: Actually it is rather difficult to see anything with your images.  Which is why the use of images in question is strongly discouraged.  And it is extremely unlikely that you would get the exact same error from both the symfony CLI and bin/console.

Comment: @Cerad `symfony console` is equal to `bin/console`... (but then running it within the Symfony CLI context, meaning you have access to the automatically generated environment variables)

Comment: @WouterJ Ah.  So that is what he is saying.

Comment: @Cerad, even with image you can read the comand I typped lol ... but btw I'm agree that images are not a good idea I will change that next time.

Answer (score 1):

The error does say it all: there are some invalid configuration options under the `doctrine_migrations` configuration.

Looking at the error, you are most likely using DoctrineMigrationsBundle 3.x with the 2.x configuration. Maybe you updated the bundle when using Composer.

There are 3 things you can do:

1. Downgrade the bundle to whatever version you previously used (e.g. 2.2)
2. Update the Symfony recipe to automatically get the new configuration: `composer recipes:install -v --force doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle`
3. Read the [UPGRADE guide](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/blob/3.1.x/UPGRADE.md#from-2x-to-300) of the DoctrineMigrationsBundle and update the configuration for 3.x.